# How do the SDA understand 'Christ's ministry in the heavenly sanctuary' based on Daniel 8:14?

Tags: prophecy, daniel, literalism, doctrine

According to fundamental Belief 24: (Christ’s ministry in the Heavenly Sanctuary) the SDA believe that Christ began his investigative judgement in 1844.This they refer to as the end of 2300 days of Daniel's prophecy.

Daniel 8:14 NASB

> 14 And he said to me, “For 2,300 evenings and mornings; then the sanctuary will be [q]properly restored.”

In the prophecy Daniel refers to the restoration of the sanctuary which the SDA clear identify as the heavenly sanctuary.But its not clear in Daniel's prophecy which one he was referring to.Should the text be understood from a literal or non literal sense.

How can one understand this interpretation of Christ ministry in the heavenly sanctuary?